# a href doesn't work in my project

Tags: html, href

I have a simple problem with my `<a href="">` code: they don't open anymore...

It only worked one time, and then no more.

I don't know why... It would be great if someone can help me with this.

my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">  
    <a href="Destaque/Destaque.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
</div
```

I tried a lot of things, but I didn't find out what the problem is.

Comment: Those data attributes look like this is from jQuery Mobile.

Comment: yes i use jquery libraries

Comment: Well jquery mobile, uses PushState and the History API to override link behavior.  Maybe if you load the page in firefox with firebug's or Chrome with the JavaScript Console open, you can get a better idea what is going wrong

Comment: what i cant understand is why on the first time the page open, and then no more

Comment: Maybe it's the relative path. On the first load you are in the folder containing the sub-folder `Destaque`, after you click on it your reference directory is `Destaque` so clicking on it again would try and resolve `Destaque/Destaque/Destaque.html`.  This behavior might not look like a a classic 404 because of jQuery Mobile (it uses ajax to load pages)

Comment: the path Destaque/Destaque/Destaque.html is try to open... you have right... and right path are only Destaque/Destaque.html...  how can i fix it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29143/discussion-between-user2232273-and-jason-sperske)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. i have find the answer for this problem.

the path i have written was right and the problem was not the relative/absolute path.

the only thing i have to add to this link is rel="external", because the html page that i want to open is in the sub-folder from my projecto.

the following code show the right code for this situation.

```
<a href="Destaque/Destaque.html" rel="external" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are experiencing a combination of broken paths and jQuery Mobile's overriding of link behavior.

On the first load you are in the folder containing the sub-folder `Destaque`, after you click on it your reference directory is `Destaque` so clicking on it again would try and resolve `Destaque/Destaque/Destaque.html`. This behavior might not look like a a classic 404 because of jQuery Mobile (it uses ajax to load pages).

To fix this use an absolute path by adding a leading `/` changing this:

```
<a href="Destaque/Destaque.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="/Destaque/Destaque.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
```

This assumes that this sub-folder is in fact in the root of your web app. If not then you need to adjust your absolute path.